# VBA Code that will delete entire line if a cell has a certain value, without setting the range manually

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of entries in Excel 2010 that lose their importance if a certain information about each entry is "YES". Therefore I want to delete those lines as soon as the certain information is set to "YES" (the field is either "YES" or "NO").

My entries look like this:

```
*valuerow1*   *valuerow1*   *valuerow1* … "YES/NO"

*valuerow2*   *valuerow2*   *valuerow2* … "YES/NO"

*valuerow3*   *valuerow3*   *valuerow3* … "YES/NO"
```

I have found code that will delete the desired lines BUT before it does, I have to set the range manually in a pop-up window. However the point of the application is, that it runs automatically and the user should not need to set a range.
Since I haven't written the following code myself and don't fully understand it because I'm totally new to coding, I fail to adapt what I have so far.
Btw the column holding the values "YES" or "NO" is column E.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub Delete_Offene_Aufträge_Zurückgegeben_Ja()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do
    Set Rng = WorkRng.Find("YES", LookIn:=xlValues)
      If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.EntireRow.Delete
      End If
        Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve your goal:

```
Sub Delete_Offene_Aufträge_Zurückgegeben_Ja()

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    lngLastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lngLastRow To 2 Step -1     'I assumed there are headers in line 1
        If wks.Range("E" & i).Value = "YES" Then
            wks.Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as desired now:)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need something simple like the below. I have set the code to a column (based on the understanding that your YES/ NO are all in the same column). Adjust it where needed.

Post the below into your worksheet module (not tested).

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'set the target column to the column in which your yes/no lies
    'adjust if you need to have a range instead of a column using intersect method
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Important note: this will delete the entire row as soon as the user selects YES. You cannot CTR+Z to undo!

Comment: My problems is already solved!
Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I just got  424-errors with your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the code and explain what's happening:

```
Sub Delete_Offene_Aufträge_Zurückgegeben_Ja()
    ' These two lines declare your Range objects
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    ' This statements "turns off" error handling. Meaning each and every error occurring
    ' will be ignored and the Sub proceeds with the next line
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Some Variant String, implying Option Explicit is not turned on
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    ' Sets one of the Range objects to the Selection, meaning all selected cells
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    ' Sets the same Range object to cells chosen by the user via inputbox
    ' Type 8 means Cell reference as range object is to be input
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    ' Turns off screen updating. Meaning Excel doesn't update the screen until
    ' this is tuned on again or the program ends.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Start a loop
    Do
        ' Set the first range object to a range with the value "YES" in it
        ' if there is one in the selected range from before
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Find("YES", LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' Checks if something was found by the Find method
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            ' Delets the row
            Rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    ' Loops until nothing is found, albeit I'm not sure that Rng is something
    ' after deletion.
    Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing
    ' Turns screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now, to do what you want you can just set your `WorkRng` to the whole column E, which is left as an exercise. You may also need to change the Loop a little, since I'm not sure if `Rng` still references something if the range was deleted. You may update your question and ping me, so I can update my answer with a revised Loop.

Whenever you take some code off the internet (Which is certainly not bad practice) you should try to understand what's happening, so it's easier to change the code, and it helps you learn VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation of the code!
I'm trying to understand code from the internet as good as possible for my level…
Anyway - nice advice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following setup, where the Headers are in the first row and the data starts from cell A2:

[image]

then the code you would need is the following:

```
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, workRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
With sht
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set workRng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
End With
For Each rng In workRng.Rows
    If Not rng.Find("YES") Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

For demonstration purposes I highlight the rows instead of deleting them. If you want to delete them you can just do:

```
rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

After the execution your data would look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.